# How to access JSF folder resources/images programmatically in backing bean?

Tags: mysql, jsf, tomcat7, managed-bean, pojo

I'm trying to save/insert the image by default in one of the column record during the user registration process.

The image source is in WebContent > resources > images of the web project in Eclipse IDE.

I need to access the said image in the ManagedBean or DAO class in order to insert the image value in the DB(MySQL) as a default value.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [getResourceAsStream](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) method on External context to read the file from `resources` folder.

```
InputStream iStream = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream("/resources/images/YOUR_IMAGE_NAME");
```

Comment: when i'm trying to assign the iStream value in my picture byte[] variable I got this error: The method setPicture(byte[]) in the type UserDetail is not applicable for the arguments (InputStream)

Comment: it's fixed now. I just added guava-17.0.jar which has the ByteStreams class needed to convert the InputStream value to byte[]. userDetail.setPicture(ByteStreams.toByteArray(iStream)); thanks @Kishor P